# Can okHTTP3 make interceptions even when an external API is making the requests?

Tags: java, android, http, okhttp

I had a general question regarding okHTTP, and I was hoping someone could clear things up for me. I want to intercept the HTTP headers on all outgoing network requests from my app. Here is the example provided on the okHTTP github:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor())
    .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://www.publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
    .header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Example")
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
response.body().close();
```

My problem is that I am using an external API to make the requests that I need in my application. Does this exclude me from being able to intercept the HTTP headers since it is the API building the request and not me? If so, is there any way to get around this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you supply the client to the api or modify it's source code?

Comment: I do believe if I disregard the client library, I think I would then be responsible for my own requests to the API.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it is always possible.  1 good answer, 3 bad answers depending on how critical it is...

1. The API will usually provide access to make changes to the default OkHttpClient it builds so you can set things like a proxy.  Try to do this first.

less clean options you probably don't want to do.

2. You can MITM attack the client yourself. e.g. something like https://www.charlesproxy.com/
3. You can probably use reflection to get into the internal APIs of the library and change the client, but this is brittle and could still be technically impossible.
4. You can attack it via java bytecode agents https://github.com/yschimke/agentdebug

Comment: Probably aop can also be used

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I will investigate each possibility to see what is the best for my particular circumstance.